Vault OIDC Bound_Claims
I am configuring Hashicorp Vault for OIDC authentication for a number of namespaces.
I have a requirement under bound_claims to be able to logical AND for groups in the token
group: A && B && CC
I can do logical OR by using
group: "a,b,c"
Is there a method for doing logical AND for checking groups?
I have also tried without success
bound_claims {
 group: "a"
 group: "b"
} 

I have looked through the source code for Terraform Vault module and it appears that
states that "The expected value may be a single string or a comma-separated string list."
